# Set one specific date type for reading in genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a huge file with `numpy.genfromtxt()`. One of the rows is formatted as a `string`, the other rows are formatted as `floats` (Example:

```
76920 1995-12-31-00:00                -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -                -     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -              108  -      -   -   -   -  -             14.3  -             17.4      -    -                -      -             14.3   -     -     -      -           1005.8      -     -      -    -   -     -    -    -     -   -              2.6  -                -    -    -    -  -    -    -  -              7.4   -  -               54              3.2              5.1  -                -                -                -                -                -                -              7.4                -                -              5.7       -      -      -       -      -      -                -        -                -                -        -                -        -       -                -      -                -                -      -    -    -                -                -                -                -                -                -                -                -    -    -        -        -    -        -      -      -    -                -              3.7                -                -                -                -                -
```

). In this case the date (1995-12-31-00:00) should be read as a `string`, and everything else as `float` (or not existing). According to the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) I can set the data type for every column separately, but I did not find a way to set the data type only for one column (in this case the second), and let the rest free for guessing. Is that possible, or do I have to write all data types down as soon as I want to specify one of them?
Furthermore, I want to set a "fallback" data type which is used if the data type is not recognized. I.e. my current output is:

```
[('Stno', '<i8'), ('DateHourNMT', 'S16'), ('CD', '<i8'), ('CD147', '?'), ('CD15', '?'), ('CD18', '?'), ('CD30', '?'), ('CD40', '?'), ('CD69', '?'), ('CD75', '?'), ('CD98', '?'), ('CV', '<f8'), ('CV147', '?'), ('CV15', '?'), ('CV18', '?'), ('CV30', '?'), ('CV40', '?'), ('CV69', '?'), ('CV75', '?'), ('CV98', '?'), ('DD', '<i8'), ('DG', '?'), ('DG_010', '?'), ('DM1', '?'), ('DMT', '?'), ('DP1', '?'), ('DX', '?'), ('FF', '<f8'), ('FG', '?'), ('FG_010', '<f8'), ('FG_020', '?'), ('FG_1', '?'), ('FX', '<f8'), ('FX_020', '?'), ('FX_1', '?'), ('H13', '?'), ('HM0LF', '?'), ('HMEAN', '?'), ('HS1MAX', '?'), ('PR', '<f8'), ('S1HMAX', '?'), ('S1MAX', '?'), ('S1MEAN', '?'), ('SDP1', '?'), ('SFP', '?'), ('SIGS1', '?'), ('SPR1', '?'), ('SPRT', '?'), ('SPRTP', '?'), ('T13', '?'), ('TA', '<f8'), ('TC', '?'), ('TD', '<f8'), ('THHF', '?'), ('THLF', '?'), ('THTP', '?'), ('TL', '?'), ('TM24', '?'), ('TMAX', '?'), ('TU', '?'), ('TW', '<f8'), ('TWB', '?'), ('UI', '?'), ('UU', '<i8'), ('WHM0', '<f8'), ('WHMAX', '<f8'), ('WL', '?'), ('WL00', '?'), ('WL10', '?'), ('WL20', '?'), ('WL30', '?'), ('WL40', '?'), ('WL50', '?'), ('WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('WTP', '<f8'), ('WTP2', '<f8'), ('WTZ', '<f8'), ('X1CD147', '?'), ('X1CD30', '?'), ('X1CD75', '?'), ('X1CV147', '?'), ('X1CV30', '?'), ('X1CV75', '?'), ('X1DD', '<i8'), ('X1DG_010', '?'), ('X1FF', '<f8'), ('X1FG_010', '<f8'), ('X1FG_020', '?'), ('X1FX', '<f8'), ('X1FX_020', '?'), ('X1HMEAN', '?'), ('X1PR', '<f8'), ('X1SDP1', '?'), ('X1TA', '<f8'), ('X1TD', '<f8'), ('X1TM24', '?'), ('X1TS', '?'), ('X1TW', '?'), ('X1UU', '<i8'), ('X1WHM0', '<f8'), ('X1WHMAX', '<f8'), ('X1WL', '<f8'), ('X1WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('X1WTP', '<f8'), ('X1WTP2', '<f8'), ('X1WTZ', '<f8'), ('X2DD', '?'), ('X2FF', '?'), ('X2FG_010', '?'), ('X2FG_020', '?'), ('X2FX', '?'), ('X2FX_020', '?'), ('X2SDP1', '?'), ('X2TM24', '?'), ('X2TW', '?'), ('X2WHM0', '<f8'), ('X2WHMAX', '<f8'), ('X2WL', '<f8'), ('X2WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('X2WTP', '<f8'), ('X2WTP2', '<f8'), ('X2WTZ', '<f8')]
```

but I want to have something like:

```
[('Stno', '<i8'), ('DateHourNMT', 'S16'), ('CD', '<i8'), ('CD147', '<f8'), ('CD15', '<f8'), ('CD18', '<f8'), ('CD30', '<f8'), ('CD40', '<f8'), ('CD69', '<f8'), ('CD75', '<f8'), ('CD98', '<f8'), ('CV', '<f8'), ('CV147', '<f8'), ('CV15', '<f8'), ('CV18', '<f8'), ('CV30', '<f8'), ('CV40', '<f8'), ('CV69', '<f8'), ('CV75', '<f8'), ('CV98', '<f8'), ('DD', '<i8'), ('DG', '<f8'), ('DG_010', '<f8'), ('DM1', '<f8'), ('DMT', '<f8'), ('DP1', '<f8'), ('DX', '<f8'), ('FF', '<f8'), ('FG', '<f8'), ('FG_010', '<f8'), ('FG_020', '<f8'), ('FG_1', '<f8'), ('FX', '<f8'), ('FX_020', '<f8'), ('FX_1', '<f8'), ('H13', '<f8'), ('HM0LF', '<f8'), ('HMEAN', '<f8'), ('HS1MAX', '<f8'), ('PR', '<f8'), ('S1HMAX', '<f8'), ('S1MAX', '<f8'), ('S1MEAN', '<f8'), ('SDP1', '<f8'), ('SFP', '<f8'), ('SIGS1', '<f8'), ('SPR1', '<f8'), ('SPRT', '<f8'), ('SPRTP', '<f8'), ('T13', '<f8'), ('TA', '<f8'), ('TC', '<f8'), ('TD', '<f8'), ('THHF', '<f8'), ('THLF', '<f8'), ('THTP', '<f8'), ('TL', '<f8'), ('TM24', '<f8'), ('TMAX', '<f8'), ('TU', '<f8'), ('TW', '<f8'), ('TWB', '<f8'), ('UI', '<f8'), ('UU', '<i8'), ('WHM0', '<f8'), ('WHMAX', '<f8'), ('WL', '<f8'), ('WL00', '<f8'), ('WL10', '<f8'), ('WL20', '<f8'), ('WL30', '<f8'), ('WL40', '<f8'), ('WL50', '<f8'), ('WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('WTP', '<f8'), ('WTP2', '<f8'), ('WTZ', '<f8'), ('X1CD147', '<f8'), ('X1CD30', '<f8'), ('X1CD75', '<f8'), ('X1CV147', '<f8'), ('X1CV30', '<f8'), ('X1CV75', '<f8'), ('X1DD', '<i8'), ('X1DG_010', '<f8'), ('X1FF', '<f8'), ('X1FG_010', '<f8'), ('X1FG_020', '?'), ('X1FX', '<f8'), ('X1FX_020', '<f8'), ('X1HMEAN', '<f8'), ('X1PR', '<f8'), ('X1SDP1', '<f8'), ('X1TA', '<f8'), ('X1TD', '<f8'), ('X1TM24', '<f8'), ('X1TS', '<f8'), ('X1TW', '<f8'), ('X1UU', '<i8'), ('X1WHM0', '<f8'), ('X1WHMAX', '<f8'), ('X1WL', '<f8'), ('X1WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('X1WTP', '<f8'), ('X1WTP2', '<f8'), ('X1WTZ', '<f8'), ('X2DD', '<f8'), ('X2FF', '<f8'), ('X2FG_010', '<f8'), ('X2FG_020', '<f8'), ('X2FX', '<f8'), ('X2FX_020', '<f8'), ('X2SDP1', '<f8'), ('X2TM24', '<f8'), ('X2TW', '<f8'), ('X2WHM0', '<f8'), ('X2WHMAX', '<f8'), ('X2WL', '<f8'), ('X2WTHMAX', '<f8'), ('X2WTP', '<f8'), ('X2WTP2', '<f8'), ('X2WTZ', '<f8')]
```

if I set the default data type as `float`. Is that possible?

Edit 2: Error-line:

```
 76920 2005-01-01-00:00               52     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -             0.06     -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -              230  -      -   -   -   -  -             10.1  -             12.3      -    -              8.5      -    -   -     -     -      -           1016.7      -     -      -    -   -     -    -    -     -   -              7.0  -              4.7    -    -    -  -    -    -  -              7.8   -  -               85              1.5              2.5  -    -    -    -    -    -    -              6.1             12.8              8.5              4.9       -      -      -       -      -      -              229        -             10.3             12.3        -              8.6        -       -           1016.8      -              7.1              4.7      -    -    -               84                -              2.8            19.88              6.8                -                -                -    -    -        -        -    -        -      -      -    -              1.5              2.4            17.40                -             12.6              5.8              4.9
```

The data is aquired by

```
self.data = numpy.genfromtxt(self.file, skip_footer=0, dtype = float, missing_values = '-', filling_values = -1000, names = True, invalid_raise = False, usemask = True, converters={0: int, 1: str})
```

Comment: Have you tried `dtype=None`? This tells `genfromtxt` to take an educated guess about the dtype of each column.

Comment: @unutbu: That only guesses partly right. Can I use a fallback value (i.e. if a value is not recognized at once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to use `dtype=None`, which tells `genfromtxt` to make an
educated guess about the dtype of each column. If that does not produce the
desired dtypes, then here are three options:

```
import numpy as np

def using_explicit_dtype(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        header = next(f).split()
        n = len(header)
        dtype = ['<i8', 'S16']+['<f8']*(n-2)
        dtype = zip(header, dtype)
        data = np.genfromtxt(f, 
                             dtype=dtype, 
                             usemask=True)
        return data

def using_default_dtype(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        header = next(f).split()
        data = np.genfromtxt(f, 
                             # filling_values=-1000, 
                             # names=True,
                             # usemask=True,
                             dtype=float, 
                             converters={0: int, 1: str})
        data.dtype.names = header
        return data

def using_pandas(filename):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_table('data', delim_whitespace=True, na_values='-')
    return df
```

`using_explicit_dtype` reads the first line of the file to build the desired
dtype explicitly. One advantage of doing it this way is that you can use
`usemask=True` to return a structured masked array. One disadvantage, however,
is that you must specify the length of the string column explicitly in advance.

`using_default_dtype` uses `dtype=float` to set a default dtype, and converters
to handle the first and second columns. Unfortunately, this is incompatible with
some other parameters, such as `filling_values=-1000`, `names=True`, and
`usemask=True`.

`using_pandas` uses [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to load the data into a
`pandas.DataFrame`. Pandas has much better support for row- and column-labeled
table-like arrays than NumPy structured arrays. You might find this a more
convenient solution than dealing with NumPy's structured arrays.

---

```
filename = 'data'
data = using_explicit_dtype(filename)
print(data)
# [ (76920, '1995-12-31-00:00', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 108.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.3, nan, 17.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.3, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1005.8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2.6, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.4, nan, nan, 54.0, 3.2, 5.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.4, nan, nan, 5.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
#  (76920, '2005-01-01-00:00', 52.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.06, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 230.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 10.1, nan, 12.3, nan, nan, 8.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1016.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.0, nan, 4.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.8, nan, nan, 85.0, 1.5, 2.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 6.1, 12.8, 8.5, 4.9, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 229.0, nan, 10.3, 12.3, nan, 8.6, nan, nan, 1016.8, nan, 7.1, 4.7, nan, nan, nan, 84.0, nan, 2.8, 19.88, 6.8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.5, 2.4, 17.4, nan, 12.6, 5.8, 4.9)]

print(data.dtype.descr[:5])
# [('Stno', '<i8'), ('DateHourNMT', '|S16'), ('CD', '<f8'), ('CD147', '<f8'), ('CD15', '<f8')]
print(type(data))
# <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
```

---

```
data2 = using_default_dtype(filename)
print(data2)
# [ (76920, '1995-12-31-00:00', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 108.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.3, nan, 17.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, 14.3, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1005.8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2.6, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.4, nan, nan, 54.0, 3.2, 5.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.4, nan, nan, 5.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
#  (76920, '2005-01-01-00:00', 52.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.06, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 230.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 10.1, nan, 12.3, nan, nan, 8.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1016.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.0, nan, 4.7, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 7.8, nan, nan, 85.0, 1.5, 2.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 6.1, 12.8, 8.5, 4.9, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 229.0, nan, 10.3, 12.3, nan, 8.6, nan, nan, 1016.8, nan, 7.1, 4.7, nan, nan, nan, 84.0, nan, 2.8, 19.88, 6.8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.5, 2.4, 17.4, nan, 12.6, 5.8, 4.9)]

print(data2.dtype.descr[:5])
# [('Stno', '<i8'), ('DateHourNMT', '|S16'), ('CD', '<f8'), ('CD147', '<f8'), ('CD15', '<f8')]

print(type(data2))
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

```
df = using_pandas(filename)
print(df)
#     Stno       DateHourNMT  CD  CD147  CD15  CD18  CD30  CD40  CD69  CD75  \
# 0  76920  1995-12-31-00:00 NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
# 1  76920  2005-01-01-00:00  52    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

#    ...    X2SDP1  X2TM24  X2TW  X2WHM0  X2WHMAX  X2WL  X2WTHMAX  X2WTP  \
# 0  ...       NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN      3.7   NaN       NaN    NaN   
# 1  ...       NaN     NaN   NaN     1.5      2.4  17.4       NaN   12.6   

#    X2WTP2  X2WTZ  
# 0     NaN    NaN  
# 1     5.8    4.9  

print(df.dtypes)
# Stno             int64
# DateHourNMT     object
# CD             float64
# ...
# X2WTP2      float64
# X2WTZ       float64
# Length: 122, dtype: object
```

Comment: That results in `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2005-01-01-00:00`

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?

Comment: My numpy version is 1.9.2

Comment: Could you post the line that contains `2005-01-01-00:00`? I'm unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added, I hope that helps. Furthermore, I added the calling code.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot -- especially the calling code. It appears there is a conflict between `names=True` and my suggested solution. A workaround would be to remove `names=True`, add `skip_header=1` to read in the data, then patch the column names with `data.dtype.names = ...` after the fact. Sorry it is so ugly; I don't see a better way. (Of course, alternatively, you could define the dtype explicitly...)

Comment: Jep, for around 120-140 values. How would I read in the data and connect it with the data afterwards? Simply via a "readline()"?

Comment: Even if I remove `names=True`, I still get this error.

Comment: @arc_lupus: `filling_values=-1000` and `usemask=True` would also need to be removed. I haven't found a way to overcome these limitations, so I posted a way to set the dtype explicitly.